# Show a group cannot have order $2n$ for some odd $n\gt 1$ and be simple (without Cauchy's Theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

We were asked to prove the following today:

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that if $G$ has order $2n$ for some odd integer $n$ greater than $1$, then $G$ contains a proper non-trivial  normal subgroup and cannot be a simple group.

We were told that Cayley's Theorem would be very beneficial to the proof but all I managed to get was to say that with a group $G$, we have a map $\varphi$ such that $$\varphi (g) = T_g $$ where $T_g$ is simply a function $G \to G$ where $T_g(x) = gx \ \ \ \forall x \in G$

Next I am told we need to show that $G$ definitely has an element of some order. Naturally I wanted to used LaGrange for this but I was told this isn't the correct approach. Searching for help after this I see that Cauchy's Theorem is used but we haven't covered that in class so we can't use that. Is there a way that I can continue from here using only Cayley's Theorem? As for a bit of reference, the exact proof of Cayley's Theorem we went over is "Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations"

After proving we were supposed to use it to show that a group of order $216$ cannot be simple. Assuming the theorem is true, I still don't know how this can be, seeing that $216 = 2*108$. $108$ is an even number so does the theorem we are supposed to prove even play a role in this case?

This has been bugging me all morning and I'm not getting any further along looking at it by myself. So any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I see how the question is similar (I even seen that one before posting this one) but the answer to it explains to take the elements of order two...but I don't have that part proven yet (and it sounds like Cauchy's Theorem going on) which we cannot use

Comment: It is unlikely you can prove that without Cauchy (or equivalent). Cauchy's Theorem is like the most fundamental theorem in group theory. The condition on the order of the group just screams "use Cauchy".

Comment: Is it's proof simple enough that perhaps I am supposed to prove Cauchy's in the middle of this proof? The only hint we were given in class from our prof was that Cayley's Theorem guarantees that there is an element of a certain order

Comment: To prove the existence of an element of order $2$ just requires a counting argument: Every non-identity element pairs with its inverse, and the identity is left out. So one of the non-identity elements must be its own inverse.

Comment: There are two proofs at wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory) It isn't really hard but for someone who just starts his adventure with group theory I think it might be a bit too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that $G$ has an element of order $2$, the answer to the (near) duplicate question applies.

Suppose all elements of $G$ are of odd order; then the map
$$f:\ G\ \longrightarrow\ G:\ g\ \longmapsto\ g^{-1},$$
has only one fixed point, which is $e$. Because $f(f(g))=g$ for all $g\in G$, the rest of $G$ is partitioned into two sets of equal size, say $m$. It follows that $|G|=2m+1$, contradicting the assumption that $G$ is even. Hence $G$ has an element of even order, say $g$ of order $2k$. Then $g^k$ is an element of order two.